# summing numerical output from input of word in python / jython

Tags: python, sum, jython, raw-input

very new to programming in general, so forgive me for my ignorance. I am trying to write a function in jython that takes an input (name), assigns each letter a value (1-26), then sums them, and prints the value.
So far, I have:

```
def enterName():
    input = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
    input = input.lower()
    output = []
    for character in input:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        output.append(number)
    print output
```

This generates a list of the individual values, but I can't figure out how to add them together. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a list? You could just do `output= 0` `output+= number`.

Answer (score 0):

For your code change `print output` to `print sum(output)`. You are printing a list only. List provides an in build option for finding sum.

Here is an alternative solution in pythonic way.

```
In [1]: sum([ord(i.lower()) - 96 for i in raw_input('Enter your name: ')])
Enter your name: Rahul
Out[1]: 60
```

If the name having spaces the above solution makes problems so i removed the spaces with `join` and `split`.

```
In [2]: sum([ord(i.lower()) - 96 for i in ''.join(raw_input('Enter your name: ').split())])
Enter your name: Rahul K P
Out[2]: 87
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple integer variable and increase it:

```
output = 0
for character in name:
    number = ord(character) - 96
    output += number
print output
```